# how to store results into a for loop of matrices applying a function at each step of the loop?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to apply a function to a matrix inside a for loop. The output should also be a matrix that changes at each step of the loop. The codes below explains my problem:

```
  I1=apply(I0, 1, func1)
  I2=apply(I1, 1, func1)
  I3=apply(I2, 1, func1)
  .
  .
  I10=apply(I9, 1, func1)
```

I0,I1,...I10 are each 4X10 matrix, func 1 is a predefined function. I've been attempting to solve this problem with a loop. I can't find much information on this. I need something like this:

```
   for(i in 1:10){
     I[i]=apply(I[i-1],1,func1)
   }
```

Comment: It's not a matter of luck, but you do need to define `I0` for this to have any meaning. It would make more sense to construct an array with dimensions `c(4,10,10)` or a list of matrices. If it's an array, the inner command would be `I[,,i]=apply(I[,,i-1],1,func1)` and if a list, `I[[i]]=apply(I[[ i-1 ],1,func1)` ... and you would need to drop the notion of having separate named objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two easy ways to go for:**

**1-  Using `get` and `assign`:**

```
# How get and assign work: 

x0 = 10 
get(paste0("x", 0)) # get the variable passed as a string argument - returns 10
assign(paste0("x", 0), 20) # assign 20 to x
print(x0) #20


# And.. the recursion 

x0 = 2 # recursive initialization

for(i in 1:5) {
  previousValue = get(paste0("x", i-1))
  thisValue = previousValue * 2 
  assign(paste0("x", i), thisValue)
}
```

[image]

.

.

**2-  Using the magic of a `list`:**

```
x0 = 2 # recursive initialization
myResults = list(x0)

# Now, the recursion!
for(i in 1:5) {
  thisValue = myResults[[i]] 
  nextValue = c(thisValue * 2)  # Some random calculation, use your function instead
  myResults[[i+1]] = nextValue  # Now add to the list 
}
```

[image]